# SQLite FOREIGN KEY Constraint

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

In my **android** project's **SqLite** database I have to create a **foreign key** which is the **primery key** of the table. I wrote the sql statement as below using **SQLiteManager**.

```
 CREATE TABLE OBTTourVehicleUpdate
(
TourHeaderCode INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,
TourVehicleProcessCode INT    NOT NULL,
VehicleCode CHAR(10),
TourStart TEXT ,
TourEnd TEXT ,
LastMilage DOUBLE,
NewMilage DOUBLE,
CONSTRAINT  FOREIGN KEY (TourHeaderCode) REFERENCES OBTTourHeader(TourHeaderCode)

);
```

It gives me an error message saying that

> Internal Error. near FOREIGN: syntax error.

The **table structure** of two tables are as below.
[image]
 how can I fix this.

Comment: show me `TourHeaderCode` table structure

Comment: OK, I'll post. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `CONSTRAINT` from your code. Just do the

```
FOREIGN KEY (TourHeaderCode) REFERENCES OBTTourHeader(TourHeaderCode).
```

Remember to call the table on the `onCreate()` and `onUpdate()` and also update the `DB_version`. And to be on the safe side, do not declare your FK as the PK too.

Comment: Ok. It works. Thanks for the advice. But this is not a my design. I'll remember "do not declare your FK as the PK too". Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You get that error because your syntax is indeed incorrect.

Read the [official SQLite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html) to learn more about how it should be used.

```
CREATE TABLE OBTTourVehicleUpdate
(
TourHeaderCode INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,
TourVehicleProcessCode INT    NOT NULL,
VehicleCode CHAR(10),
TourStart TEXT ,
TourEnd TEXT ,
LastMilage DOUBLE,
NewMilage DOUBLE,
FOREIGN KEY(TourHeaderCode) REFERENCES OBTTourHeader(TourHeaderCode)
);
```

Something like that should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE OBTTourVehicleUpdate
(
TourHeaderCode INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,
TourVehicleProcessCode INT    NOT NULL,
VehicleCode CHAR(10),
TourStart TEXT ,
TourEnd TEXT ,
LastMilage DOUBLE,
NewMilage DOUBLE,
FOREIGN KEY(TourHeaderCode) REFERENCES OBTTourHeader(TourHeaderCode)
);
```

You don't need to use `CONSTRAINT` in your query. Follow this article about [Foreign Key Constraints](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_basics)

Comment: Yep, It works. I used "CONSTRAINT" by think of SQL statement. Thank you!

Comment: @SamanthaWithanage Don't care. it's a common programming mistake :)